# Controlling where HTTP requests go in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

If I have a static site on AWS S3 (and maybe using CloudFront) that's pretty cool, because it scales easily, and has zero-downtime deployments, because you're just updating static assets, and gets distributed to edge locations, woohoo!

But, if I want to have a contact form, or process a stripe payment. I need to run some backend code. So, how do I tell AWS that for GETs to certain routes, use S3 (or CloudFront), but if there's a form submit, direct that to this little Lambda function over here?

Could I use Route53 and direct everything at `example.com/forms/...` over to Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route53 is just DNS, it doesn't do any routing based on the path. Since you are using CloudFront I believe you can use the CloudFront Behaviors feature to perform the routing you are talking about, like what is described in [this blog post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-amazon-cloudfront-application-router-chris-iona). Alternatively, just use a different subdomain for the dynamic parts of your web application like api.example.com for your API Gateway routes.

Comment: I would use subdomains, but then form actions can't be relative paths, and testing locally gets a bit challenging. Thanks!!!