# How to run socket.io on my static site on AWS

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

If I have a static site on AWS S3 (and maybe using CloudFront) that's pretty cool, because it scales easily, and has zero-downtime deployments, because you're just updating static assets, and gets distributed to edge locations, woohoo!

But, if I wanted to have a little live chat support feature using Socket.io on the contact page, how would I tell Amazon to deal with Websockets? Could I use Route53 to do something different with Websocket requests to a particular domain, like redirect them to Lambda? (Lambda can't run socket.io can it?)

Comment: As far as I know you will need to run socket.io on an EC2 server. You won't be able to run it on Lambda.

Comment: @Costa, 
Have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40950248/1695906), the answer here involves the fact that DNS is not involved in path resolution, so Route 53 is not a factor in this question.

Socket.io is almost certainly going to require a server and connecting through CloudFront seems unlikely.

Although I am not versed in socket.io's underlying transport protocol(s?), I don't see a way around this.  CloudFront is a reverse proxy that only supports proper, standard HTTP request/response behavior, which is not well-suited to real-time event-oriented operations. CloudFront does not support websockets, though Socket.io may not need them and may have the flexibility to fall back to a compatible behavior but it will -- at best -- be suboptimal if possible at all, because even with long-polling (inefficient), you're limited to under 30 seconds for a single response, because CloudFront has a fixed timeout timer of 30 seconds, that cannot be modified.

Similarly, Lambda functions accessed through API Gateway are suited only to handling a single HTTP request/response cycle, not anything persistent and no intrinsic mechanism for handling "state" across requests.

My assumption going in would be that you'd need one or more servers behind an ELB Classic Load Balancer with SSL and operating in TCP mode, using a subdomain of your site's domain, connecting browsers to the back-end for persistent connections.

Even if this answer is helpful, I'm honestly not certain that it is sufficiently helpful... so you may wish to hold off on accepting it, since someone may come along and offer an answer that delves more deeply into the internals of socket.io and how that is going to interoperate with CloudFront, if such interoperation is possible.

Comment: is there any solution that has come up for this issue since your answer?